# Count Match value in DataFrame based on list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dataframe, string-matching

I have a dataframe, which has some items title for example

```
ratings_dict = {
    "TYPE": ["Testing","Headphone","Iphone","AC","Laptop","Monitor"],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(ratings_dict)
```

Want to count the value based on a given list:

```
Search_history=['test','phone','lap','testing','tes','iphone','Headphone','head','Monitor','ac']
```

Expected output:

[image]

Note: In the case, the word "phone" is matched with 2 values in the dataframe "Headphone" and "Iphone" then Count will increment for both.

Any suggestion or code snippet will be helpful.

Comment: Please don't use images in your question: they are not searchable, nor can they be copy-pasted. Create copy-pasteable code, e.g., your sample dataframe could include the code needed to create it.

Comment: "Any suggestion or code snippet will be helpful.": and what have *you* already tried yourself? That helps us guide you better.

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html may be helpful.

Comment: Hi thank you for your reply, I already tried `df.str.contains` method but was unable to get the count of matches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert everything to lowercase then count the number of times a TYPE is a substring of a search history item and vice versa

```
import pandas as pd

ratings_dict = {
    "TYPE": ["Testing","Headphone","Iphone","AC","Laptop","Monitor"],
}
df = pd.DataFrame(ratings_dict)

Search_history=['test','phone','lap','testing','tes','iphone','Headphone','head','Monitor','ac']

# convert everything to lower case
Search_history = [ x.lower() for x in Search_history]
df['TYPE'] = [ x.lower() for x in df.TYPE]

# count up the number of times one of the TYPEs is a substring of a Search_history or a Search_history is a substring of a TYPE
df['count'] = [ sum( x in y or y in x for y in Search_history) for x in df.TYPE]
```

Answer (score 0):

It's up to you to define what conditions make sense, your question is a bit too loose. You could either check if the values match, of you could convert some list values into default ones before they are checked as well